# R add Column to dataframe based on previous column if present

Tags: r, merge

I would like to add a column to a dataframe based on a value in a second dataframe. However, if the column is not present in the second dataframe I would like to add a default value. For example, if my second dataframe contains

```
> dataframe2$contents
[1] A A C A C T
```

I am merging on a common "id" column using:

```
Merged <- merge(dataframe1, dataframe2, by="id") 
# I actually only need the contents column from dataframe2
```

This works great however, in some cases when merging the tables there will be no "contents" column in dataframe2. If that's the case I still want a contents column, but I want to fill it with "G".

Comment: Please provide sample `dataframe1` and `dataframe2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(is.na(match("contents",colnames(Merged)))) Merged$contents<-"G"
```

If after merging there is no column named `contents` then add column with default value "G".